# How do I call arbitrary method of a struct in Rust?

Tags: rust

How do I implement a way to call a method with an arbitrary name and access the called name inside of a common handler?

```rust
struct S;


impl S {
    fn __callattr__(&self, name: &str, val: i64) {
        println!("You called {} with argument {}", name, val);
    }
}


fn main() {
    let s = S;
    s.myfunc(25);  // I want it to work as s.__callattr__("myfunc", 25);
}
```

I guess it may be impossible because it can't be solved even on macros level winthin the syntax I need according to this question but maybe I am wrong:

[How to call methods on self in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120455/how-to-call-methods-on-self-in-macros)

Comment: It seems there is no easy way. I can only come up with an idea to define an independent macro to call the method, without same syntax exactly.

Comment: Rust doesn't have these kinds of runtime refelction facilities.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Having to type `s.__callattr__("myfunc", 25)` instead of `s.myfunc(25)` doesn't seem to be a useful goal, so it looks like your actual goal is something else.

Comment: Do you want the function name to be a dynamic value at runtime? If so, what's your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Rust supports function pointers, closures, and function trait that can all be used to define a collection capable of holding a set of methods from which to select and invoke. However, your question suggests a simple `match` statement is sufficient...

```
fn main() {
    let s = S;
    match selector_of_some_kind() {
       1 => s.method_1(25),
       2 => s.method_2(25),
       3 => s.method_3(25), 
    }
}

fn selector_of_some_kind() -> u8 {...}

struct S;

impl S {
    fn method_1(arg: i32){}
    fn method_2(arg: i32){}
    fn method_3(arg: i32){}
}
```

It occurs to me you may also be seeking the strategy pattern...
[Strategy (aka Policy)](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/strategy.html)

Answer (score -1):

The right approach is to define a trait with a single method, and then create a proper struct that implements the function you want. If you want to use variables, representing a general trait (so whatever specific structure, that implements your method), you need to Box these traits (more about it here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/dyn.html).

A simple example is here, if F1 e.g. implements your "myfunc" and F2 "some_other_func" (but both are called just "call"), that's probably what you're looking for.

```
trait Caller {
    fn call(&self, val: u64);
}

struct F1 {}
impl Caller for F1 {
    fn call(&self, val: u64) {
        println!("F1 called with {}", val);
    }
}

struct F2 {}
impl Caller for F2 {
    fn call(&self, val: u64) {
        println!("F2 called with {}", val);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_func = "f2";
    let caller: Box<dyn Caller> = match my_func {
        "f1" => Box::new(F1{}),
        "f2" => Box::new(F2{}),
        _ => panic!("unknown function {}", my_func),
    };
    caller.call(25);
}
```

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dd688fffc1928d24e8d49585e7e9442c